# How do I enable MDBs in Liberty Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

How do I enable MDBs in Liberty Bluemix?

I' ve tried adding mdb-3.1 to the list of features

[image]

However I've got this error message in the logs

```
App/0
[ERROR ] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application myapp. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.jms.MessageListener
```

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace of the exception?  Note, that MDB support does not require JMS, so mdb-3.1 does not include it (for example, you could have a custom resource adapter that uses its own interface).  Have you tried enabling a JMS feature or jmsMdb-3.1?

Comment: Try to add jms-2.0 feature.

Comment: @Leo - Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Also, ensure that jmsMdb-3.1 is enabled when setting jms-2.0.